# Returning an int in the main function of C

Tags: c, return, program-entry-point

I learned that in C++, int main() can be left without a return-statement, at which point it defaults to returning 0.
I am wondering if this is also true in C? Would the program cause an error if the function definition is `int main()`, but its body doesn't contain a return statement?

Comment: Did you look in the standard? This is your first stop on questions like this.

Comment: Since the C99 standard the [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function) function in C have the same behavior.

Comment: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function  and bookmark that site for other questions you may have.